# Connecting to ODBC with IP

Tags: php, html, sql-server

Question: How can I connect my sql database from my dedicated server?
Example:

```
$conn = odbc_connect('175.34.73.13','User_LoginDB','User123','testtest');
```

That IP is my Server IP and my database is on my server. 
I get this error when I use that code:

> expects parameter 4 to be long, string given in register.php

My HTML and PHP skills are not at all good. Suggestions?

Comment: Looks like part of the error is missing. What 'expects parameter 4 to be a long'? My guess is that it has *nothing* to do with the connection to the database.

Comment: According to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) your *"odbc_connect"* parameters may be incorrect.

Comment: PHP Warning:  odbc_connect() expects parameter 4 to be long, string given in /home/user/public_html/test/register.php on line 5. Line 5 = $conn = odbc_connect('175.34.73.13','User_LoginDB','User123','testtest');

Comment: Any suggestions on how to connect to the server? I can't use this; Server= UserPC/SQLEXPRESS, I need to use an IP. If I take away the IP it only works for local use. I need people to be able to register.

Answer (score 0):

You have `'testtest'` as the cursor type:

```
resource odbc_connect ( string $dsn , string $user , string $password [, int $cursor_type ] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

Comment: odbc_connect(Database , user, password) never seen cursor_type

Comment: added link to answer.

Comment: $dsn should be the name of a valid data source not IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.odbc-connect.php): parameter 4th should be cursor_type(int). First argument of this method can be a DSN-less connection string. This is how you can provide DB name.

```
// Replace the value of these variables with your own data
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
$server = 'serverName\instanceName';
$database = 'database';

// No changes needed from now on
$connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server;DATABASE=$database"; 
$conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass);
```

You just need to define first 4 variables with your values.

Comment: More about DSN-less connection string types you can read at [link](http://www.carlprothman.net/Technology/ConnectionStrings/ODBCDSNLess/tabid/90/Default.aspx)

Comment: DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server| Server should be my IP correct?

Comment: Yes. "Server" can be IP.

Comment: lol, you don't understand how long I've been dealing with this. I have it working on my local server (Desktop and using WAMP) using this: $conn = odbc_connect('User_LoginDB','User123','testtest'); But, I put it on my webserver and I get the no datasource error. I tried the connection string you provided. I still get that error.

Comment: What error do you get in case with string provider ? And can you show me how do you use it, please ?